# Addition of two queries - SQL/HANA

Tags: sql, hana

Trying to execute the following HANA Query.
The following Query generates the TotalBal Between '01.07.2020' AND '31.03.2021'
If this query returns 1000.

```
SELECT T1."AcctName", SUM(T0."Debit") - SUM(T0."Credit") as TotalBal
FROM TABLE0 T0  
        INNER JOIN TABLE1 T1 ON T0."Account" = T1."AcctCode" 
        INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T0."TransId" = T2."TransId"
WHERE T1."AcctCode" = '12345' AND
T0."RefDate" BETWEEN '01.07.2020' AND '31.03.2021'
GROUP BY T1."AcctName"
```

And this query where dates are between '01.01.0001' AND '06.30.2021' returns 500, so the final result should be 1500.

```
SELECT T1."AcctName", SUM(T0."Debit") - SUM(T0."Credit") as PreviousBal
FROM TABLE0 T0  
        INNER JOIN TABLE1 T1 ON T0."Account" = T1."AcctCode" 
        INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T0."TransId" = T2."TransId"
WHERE T1."AcctCode" = '12345' AND
T0."RefDate" BETWEEN '01.01.0001' AND (add_days('01.07.2020', -1))
GROUP BY T1."AcctName"
```

So, I combining them I am getting this but its not working. Any help will highly be appreciated.

```
SELECT T1."AcctName", SUM(Balance)
FROM 
(
  SELECT SUM(T0."Debit") - SUM(T0."Credit") as Balance
  FROM TABLE0 T0  
        INNER JOIN TABLE1 T1 ON T0."Account" = T1."AcctCode" 
        INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T0."TransId" = T2."TransId"
        WHERE T1."AcctCode" = '12345' AND
        T0."RefDate" BETWEEN '01.07.2020' AND '31.03.2021'

        UNION ALL

  SELECT SUM(T0."Debit") - SUM(T0."Credit") as Balance
  FROM TABLE0 T0  
        INNER JOIN TABLE1 T1 ON T0."Account" = T1."AcctCode" 
        INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T0."TransId" = T2."TransId"
   WHERE T1."AcctCode" = '12345' AND
   T0."RefDate" BETWEEN '01.01.0001' AND (add_days('01.07.2020', -1))
)
GROUP BY T1."AcctName"
```

Comment: I don't think your using mysql so you should remove that tag.

When you say it's "not working"?  Are you getting an error message?  Are you getting different results than you would expect?  Also why use union instead of just expanding your WHERE?

Comment: Hana , sql-server, sql, mysql ??? You forgot Oracle, MongoDB, Cassandra, Hive, Neo4J and so on

Comment: @nacho. If you see carefully, the only difference bettwen SQL and HANA is double quotes. i.e column name should be in double quotes. So I tagged all as its similar.

Comment: No, yo tagged sql-server and mysql too and then removed them

Comment: There is no "AcctName" in the union queries - and FROM ( ... ) has no alias name. The above query won't run.

Comment: @KeithJohnHutchison I have posted working code below but I am unable to get T1."AcctName". Your help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the way the two individual queries are combined is wrong.

The `UNION`ed subqueries do not project the `AcctName` column required for grouping the results.

The textual description of what the queries are supposed to do in the original question misleadingly states that the data ranges used in the two queries overlap.
Looking at the actual SQL code examples for the queries, it is clear, that Q2 is intended to cover all data valid for time **before** the data range in Q1.

One way to combine the query is the `UNION` that was tried by the OP.
For that to work, the queries need to expose the same columns, especially those required for the `GROUP BY` operation:

```
SELECT 
    UQ."AcctName", SUM(UQ."TotalBal") as "TotalBal"
FROM
    (SELECT T1."AcctName", SUM(T0."Debit") - SUM(T0."Credit") as TotalBal
    FROM TABLE0 T0  
            INNER JOIN TABLE1 T1 ON T0."Account" = T1."AcctCode" 
            INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T0."TransId" = T2."TransId"
    WHERE T1."AcctCode" = '12345' AND
    T0."RefDate" BETWEEN '01.07.2020' AND '31.03.2021'
    GROUP BY T1."AcctName"
  UNION ALL
    SELECT T1."AcctName", SUM(T0."Debit") - SUM(T0."Credit") as TotalBal
    FROM TABLE0 T0  
            INNER JOIN TABLE1 T1 ON T0."Account" = T1."AcctCode" 
            INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T0."TransId" = T2."TransId"
    WHERE T1."AcctCode" = '12345' AND
    T0."RefDate" BETWEEN '01.01.0001' AND (add_days('01.07.2020', -1))
    GROUP BY T1."AcctName") UQ
GROUP BY UQ."AccrtName";
```

This, however, is a rather naive way to achieve the result that will result in worse than necessary performance on most DBMS.

A better way for achieving the same result is to see that all we do here is **expanding** the selected date range, *while ensuring that the selected range is still **contiguous***.

With this requirement the query can be rewritten just by adjusting the `WHERE` clause:

```
 SELECT T1."AcctName", SUM(T0."Debit") - SUM(T0."Credit") as TotalBal
    FROM TABLE0 T0  
            INNER JOIN TABLE1 T1 ON T0."Account" = T1."AcctCode" 
            INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T0."TransId" = T2."TransId"
    WHERE 
            T1."AcctCode" = '12345' 
       
       AND '01.01.0001' <= T0."RefDate"  -- new "outer" minimum date (from Q2)
       AND '31.03.2021' >= T0."RefDate"  -- new "outer" maximum date (from Q1)
 
    GROUP BY T1."AcctName";
```

This works, since Q2 is always "filling up" the complete date range **before** Q1.

Comment: Thanks its working.  01.01.0001' <= 'startDate' AND 'endDate' >= T0."RefDate". Really apprecaite it. Thank you again... God bless bro.

Comment: Hello bro, can you please share your wisdom on this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67816114/union-of-multiple-database-queries-with-same-parameters thanks.